# Is it a good idea to put big temp files into a guava cache?

Tags: java, storage, guava

I have recently found out that guavas caches have a weight system that you can use instead of just counting the objects for limiting. I currently have a project where I use multiple >100MB files that are automatically downloaded when needed, since they are normally only used once in a period of ~5 days. However, it can sometimes occur that these files are instead needed 5 times in under 1 hour. However, since this is completely unpredictable, it downloads the files 5 times. Now, my question is: would it be a good idea to make a cache with `URL` -> `File` where the objects weight value is equal to its size (I would, of course, register a handler that deletes the actual file when it is removed from the cache), and would the code of guavas cache system properly manage it and delete unused stuff, or would it just throw out the big files when there is too much in the cache and leave the smaller ones always in there?

Comment: Guava's cache cares more about how frequently a thing is used than how big it is.

Comment: But if the cache is full, will guava rather delete a thing that has only been used once or one that is really big?

Comment: The thing that has only been used once.